# Can we use Regular Expression to pass as variables in Tesseract?

Tags: java, tess4j

Can we improve Tesseract character recognition accuracy by regular expression.
For example we tell to Tesseract that the text can have this kind of structure.

**4characters2Digits[4Digits]3char4Digits2char**

// Our string in the image is "abcd12[2222]aBc000AB"

// Our regular expression can be like this

```
String reg = "[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{2}\[\d{4}\][a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}";
```

I think this kind Tesseract will do better recognition for characters.

And We also can set

```
tesseract.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789[]abc...Z");
```

**Note:** I am using Java Language. Tess4j

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`bazaar`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) pattern, which supports a limited subset of Regex.

Comment: this link is broken